# Why is my admob ads not Showing on final release apk (signed) but Shows perfectly on debugs apk (not signed)?

Tags: debugging, admob, ads, release

Please guys I need help. I integrated admob ads in to my app, it works perfectly with test IDs and Real IDs when I build in debug mode, Good. But as soon as I sign my app, it stops showing ads.

Note : Real IDs work on debug apk (requests, impressions, clicks)
     : My admob account is 1 month old and still active (no violations)
     : I have both the Release apk and debug apk on my phone (Release apk (signed) does not show ads while Debug apk (unsigned) show ads perfectly)
     : I have try each of them seperatly on two different devices with different google accounts, result still the same.

The problem arise after signing. Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

Answer (score 0):

it can be cause because on debug it's test ad and when you do a release app you need put in mediation a sources of ad. Did you try to connect your phone to your computer and execute the programme with android studio? if no you will have the error with out using automatically test ad. you can have test ad with your real id when it's virtual phone. when i hade this error i put in mediation had sources of the ad and i put facebook audience network. know it's working. if you have any problem i would be happy to help you.